# How can I pass an ifstream as argument to std::thread function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I did  some  research  googling regarding the usage of `std::ifstream` within  a thread as function argument, but managed to find  its  C implementation in pthread.  What I want is for it to be implemented  in  C++11, as I am using standard C++ threads.

I am trying to pass a `std::ifstream` as argument to thread, but I get the following error:

> error: no type named `type` in `class std::result_of<void (*(std::basic_ifstream<char>))(std::basic_ifstream<char>)>`
>   `typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;`

How do I pass the `ifstream` argument to the function being called on thread?
Here's my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void file_func_1(std::ifstream m_file)
{
    // ifstream m_file;
    string line;
    while (getline(m_file, line)) {
        cout << "the line now in is" << line
             << "from thread" << std::this_thread::get_id()
             << endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds((rand() % 10) + 1));
    }
}

void file_func_2(ifstream m_file)
{
    string line;
    while (getline(m_file, line)) {
        cout << "the line now in is" << line
             << "from thread" << std::this_thread::get_id()
             << endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds((rand() % 10) + 1));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::ifstream m_file;
    m_file.open("File_line.txt", ios::in);
    int name=8;
    std::thread func_th1(file_func_1, (m_file));
    // thread func_th2(file_func_2,m_file);
    func_th1.join();
    // func_th2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanx @Toby Speight  for  editing  my question  :)  but   actually  i tried  this  code  for around 4-5  hours  and was so  frustrated  regarding  the error that  i forgot  some  grammatical errors and indentation actually  i really am i dire  need of  a solution  now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues here. The first is that you can't pass streams by value, you need to pass them by reference.

Second, it appears that you can't pass a stream via a thread directly (although there are probably work-arounds [EDIT: `std::ref` appears to work, despite comments - maybe it's a version issue as I'm using g++ with c++1z] ).

So, make your functions access references, and call your functions using a lambda when creating the thread:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void file_func_1(std::ifstream &m_file){
    string line;
    while ( getline (m_file,line) ){
        cout<<"the line now in is"<<line<<"from thread"<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds((rand() % 10) + 1));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::ifstream m_file;
    m_file.open("File_line.txt",ios::in);
    int name=8;
    std::thread func_th1([&m_file]() { file_func_1(m_file); });
    std::thread func_th2(file_func_1, ref(m_file));
    func_th1.join();
    func_th2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

And don't forget that only one thread at a time should access the stream, so wrap access in a mutex of some sort.

Comment: You could just use `std::ref`, no lambda would be required.

Comment: thanx  a lot :)  the thing is when i am trying to access the file from 2 threads  which  i created  they  start   from a  random  line and  go on continously  but as you  said  , i have  to  wrap  that using  mutex  i will  follow that

Comment: i  tried std::ref  but it  is  not   working  for me  in c++11  it  gives some  error regarding  reference  binding

Comment: @IanM_Matrix1  i am  curious  about knowing  the solution  of  that  workaround  could you please  share it with me

Comment: I would have assumed `std::ref` would have worked, but you can always pass a pointer instead. In fact a shared_ptr or unique_ptr to your stream may be safer than having to remember to ensure all your threads are done with your stream before your stream goes out of scope.

Comment: thanx  :) ws this method the other workaround you were speaking of

Comment: another thing i want to ask,it realtes to the same scenario the file contains around 1000 lines.So,the thing i am trying now is,i want to create threads according to value passed from argument that is i want to create threads iteratively .For example if i pass 3 from command line 3 threads are run but only three times what i want is i want them to run concurrently printing each thread 1000 times.